# How to debug php webapp in eclipse?

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging

I want to give the URL on my localhost, set POST variables and debug it and go... How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [PHP Development Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/) with the required PHP debugger.